# Cannot cast NSString in Label.text

Tags: swift, nsstring, nsdictionary

I've been trying to display in a label the retrieved value from a cell in another View Controller

This is the detail View Controller

```
var gg = NSDictionary()
    var siteName = NSString()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        siteName = gg["SiteName"]! as! NSString
        print(siteName)

        self.siteNameDetail.text = siteName as String
    }
```

Printing the site name gives out the value perfectly
but when cast for siteNameDetail.text is gives this error

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

This gg is retrieved from the Master Page

```
if (segue.identifier == "siteSegue"){
            let destview = segue.destinationViewController as! SiteViewController
            destview.gg = sender as! NSDictionary
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is not related to the type casting mentioned in the headline.

If the key `SiteName` does not exist in the dictionary the forced unwrapping causes the app to crash.

You have to check the key with optional binding or with the nil coalescing operator.

Use native Swift types (`String`, `Dictionary`). It makes things much easier.

```
var gg = [String:AnyObject]()
var siteName = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    siteName = gg["SiteName"] as? String ?? ""
    print(siteName)

    self.siteNameDetail.text = siteName
}
```

PS: Get rid of the ObjC legacy like semicolons and parentheses around `if` conditions.

Comment: SiteName Exists and the print(siteName) returns the name
but when I try to put it inside the siteNameDetail.text its giving me the same error
tried your method but still same error

Comment: Then `siteNameDetail` is most likely `nil` (not connected). Check that.

Comment: Thank you! that was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In the statement

```
self.siteNameDetail.text = siteName as String;
```

self might be nil, self.setNameDetail might be nil, siteName might be nil, siteName as String might be nil. You made some assumption which one the error refers to. Your assumption may be wrong.

Comment: `self` can't be `nil`,

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to cast as a NSString?

```
    siteName = gg["SiteName"]! as! String
    self.siteNameDetail.text = siteName
```

Should be enough

Comment: If printing siteName between the two lines give a good string, then it must be that siteNameDetail isn't connected properly, or it isn't a label?